# Type switch does not detect float32

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    printType(4.0)
}

func printType(i interface{}) {
    switch i := i.(type) {
    case float32:
        fmt.Println("This is a float type", i)
    }
}
```

For some reason this code does not detect `4.0` value as `float32` but it detects it as `float64` - why is that? I run it on win x64 machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For some reason this code does not detect 4.0 value as float32 but it detects it as float64 - why is that?

Because `float64` is the [default type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) for an untyped floating-point constant.  Relevant part emphasized:

> An untyped constant has a default type which is the type to which the constant is implicitly converted in contexts where a typed value is required, for instance, in a short variable declaration such as i := 0 where there is no explicit type. **The default type of an untyped constant is** bool, rune, int, **float64**, complex128 or string respectively, **depending on whether it is a** boolean, rune, integer, **floating-point**, complex, or string **constant**.